# Dynamic Task Mapping with Decorators in Airflow 2.3

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

I want a whole task group to run on the output of a single task, where both task and task group are defined via decorators - @task and @task_group respectively.

Somewhat similar to

[image: Goal]

For that, I updated one of the examples provided by Airflow. The `get`'s output is fixed, but in reality it varies:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task, task_group

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 1)
}

@dag(dag_id='xcom_taskflow_dag', schedule_interval='@daily', default_args=default_args, catchup=False)
def taskflow():

    @task()
    def get():
        return {"data":[('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B')]}

    @task_group(group_id='group')
    def group(data: dict):
        tasks = []
        for i, d in enumerate(data):
            @task(task_id=f'subtask_{i}')
            def unitask(d):
                return {"result": d}

            task_result = unitask(d)
            tasks.append(task_result)
        return tasks

    group(get())

dag = taskflow()
```

The error I get is:

```bash
TypeError: 'XComArg' object is not iterable
```

Debugging the variable data variable, I see that it is a string:

```py
{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get', dag_id='xcom_taskflow_dag', key='return_value') }}
```

1. Is there a reasonable way to render `data` so as to be able to
   access it as a `get`'s output instance?
2. Is any architectural
   principle being violated?
3. What would be an alternative way to
   achieve the final goal?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to create tasks dynamically based on the result of the task `get`, this result is only available at runtime. Instead, you can use the new concept [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) to create multiple task at runtime. You can do that with or without `task_group`, but if you want the `task_group` just to group these tasks, it will be useless because they are already grouped in one task on the UI:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task, task_group

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 1)
}


@dag(dag_id='xcom_taskflow_dag', schedule_interval='@daily', default_args=default_args, catchup=False)
def taskflow():
    @task()
    def get():
        return [('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B')]

    @task_group(group_id='group')
    def group(data):
        @task(task_id=f'subtask')
        def unitask(t):
            return {"result": t[1]}

        tasks_result = unitask.expand(t=data)
        return tasks_result

    group(get())


dag = taskflow()
```

[image: dag]

And if you have a dict format for the data in the method `get` and you don't want to change them in this task, you can create an intermediate task which read the `get` result and return a list, then use the result of the new task as input for your group.

Comment: Is it possible to implement task mapping without a decorator? Especially for a task group?

Comment: @MemphisMeng these docs have examples with both the TaskFlow API (the task decorator) and the classic/traditional operators if it helps. https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamic-tasks