# airflow "params" not passed to @task_group() function

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to get the "params" to a task group, as they are with a pain task?

```
@dag(dag_id='start-matrix', 
     params={"a" : 1, "b" : 2},
     schedule_interval=None,
     start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 5, 15, 0))
def startMatrix():
    @task()
    def mytask(params=None):
        # This works
        a = params["a"]
        pass

    @task_group()
    def mygroup(params=None):
        # This throws an error that params is not defined. 
        a = params["a"]
        pass

    pass
```

When I load this dag file, I get an error that params is not defined in mygroup. I am running 2.5.
Is there another way to access the params dict?

Answer (score 2):

Airflow context is only accessible from tasks in runtime, and TaskGroup is not a task, it's just a collection of tasks used to group the tasks in the UI.

But `params` is accessible from the TaskGroup tasks:

```py
@task_group()
def mygroup(params=None):
    @task
    def task1():
        return params["a"]
    task1()
```

Comment: Ah okay, I was hoping to create a variable number of sub taskgroups based on a number provided in the params at dag run time. Is that even possible then?

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your comment to Hussein's answer: maybe dynamically mapping over task groups could be the answer?

As of Airflow 2.5.0 you can do the following:

```py
    @task_group(
        group_id="group1"
    )
    def tg1(my_num):
        
        @task
        def add_one(num):
            return num + 1
        
        add_one(my_num)

    tg1.expand(my_num=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This would create 5 parallel task groups (one for each element in the list provided) See also [these docs](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/task-groups#generate-task-groups-dynamically-at-runtime). There are some caveats in that you can't see these task groups yet in the Airflow UI, this is soon to be added ([#28392](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28392), [#28208](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28208)). Also there is some unexpected behavior if an upstream task provides the list over which you map, this too should be fixed soon([28592](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28592)).

Disclaimer: I work at Astronomer (who wrote the docs at the first link). :)

Comment: Thanks very much, I have read through lots of the Astronomer docs, they are very helpful. My goal is to iterate over a variable parameter space that is supplied as a parameter to the DAG, where each iteration runs through a series of tasks (contained in a task group) in serial order (not parallel). I am just not seeing how to do that. I feel like it is possible with a subdag, but I avoided it cause the comments in the code say it is deprecated in favor of task groups.

Comment: Yeah the combination of making the task groups sequential and setting their number dynamically is really tricky. I tried a few things but yes I think this is currently not possible. Before resorting to subdags I would try to use [dynamic DAGs](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamically-generating-dags) that depend on each other by datasets and are generated from a script that is called with the user input from a "dag 0".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what you stated as your goal:

> to create a variable number of sub taskgroups based on a number provided in the params at dag run time.

with a combination of two other answers:

[airflow dynamic task group range creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875769/airflow-dynamic-task-group-range-creation/76877125)

[Dynamic Task Mapping with Decorators in Airflow 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73434587/dynamic-task-mapping-with-decorators-in-airflow-2-3)

My Airflow version is behind at 2.3.2 so I wasn't able to take advantage of dynamic task mapping with the `@task_group` decorator. [Astronomer docs on this feature for more info](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/task-groups?tab=taskflow#generate-task-groups-dynamically-at-runtime) but the first StackOverflow link above demonstrates that as well.

For context, we wanted to have a default config param that we'd use most of the time, but make it customizable.

My solution using `context['dag_run']`:

```py
TIMES_TO_RUN_KEY = 'times_to_run'

DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
    TIMES_TO_RUN_KEY: 3
}

@task
def retrieve_input(**context):
    # NOTE: context['params'][TIMES_TO_RUN_KEY] will ONLY get the default
    # i.e. 3 in this example
    # dag_run.conf will correctly retrieve the custom value
    # e.g. if you run it with {'times_to_run': 10}
    result = context['dag_run'].conf[TIMES_TO_RUN_KEY]
    return list(range(result))  # e.g. [1, 2, 3] for {'times_to_run': 3}

# you can also use the @dag decorator
with DAG(
    "my_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1, tz="America/Toronto"),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    params=DEFAULT_PARAMS,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:
    @task_group(group_id='run_my_tasks')
    def run_my_tasks(times_to_run_range):
        @task(task_id='my_task')
        def my_task(my_index):
            return f"Output {my_index}"

        tasks_result = my_task.expand(my_index=times_to_run_range)
        return tasks_result


    run_my_tasks(retrieve_input())
```