# airflow dynamic task group range creation

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I am trying to create airflow task group dynamically based on user input provided.
As like example given below, but here we want number of task groups created based on user input provided (without hard coding).

`

```
    sub_groups = []
    for s_id in range(1,3):
        @task_group(group_id=f"sub_group{s_id}")
        def tg2():
            st1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task1")
            st2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task2")
            st1 >> st2
        sub_groups.append(tg2())
    
    t1 >> sub_groups >> t2
    groups.append(tg1())
    groups[0] >> groups[1]
```

How to bring this attribute from user input or dag params ?

https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/task-groups#generate-task-groups-dynamically-at-runtime

we referred the above link, but it has static number of groups. which is not working for our use case.

Expectation is number of task group should come user.

Answer (score 2):

Follow @RNHTTR answer

When you trigger the dag in the confuguration add param `number_of_groups`

also set render_template_as_native_obj=Truein the dag definition

```py
    @task
    def get_number_of_groups(dag_run=None):
       return list(range(0,dag_run.conf["number_of_groups"]))

    @task_group(group_id="group1")
    def tg1(my_num):
        @task
        def print_num(num):
            return num

        @task
        def add_42(num):
            return num + 42

        print_num(my_num) >> add_42(my_num)

    tg1_object = tg1.expand(my_num=get_no_groups())
```

Comment: [Some docs on triggering a dag with configuration](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-params#pass-params-to-a-dag-run-at-runtime)

Comment: Note: mapping over task_groups is only available as of Airflow 2.5

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use dynamic task mapping. You can use dynamic task mapping for single tasks or for [task groups](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-over-a-task-group).

EDIT: The example in the Astronomer documentation you shared doesn't have to be static. Instead of calling

```py
tg1_object = tg1.expand(my_num=[19, 23, 42, 8, 7, 108])
```

You could pass the result of a different task:

```py
import random

...

@task
random_length_list():
    l = []
    for i in range(0, random.randint(0, 7)):
        l.append(i)
    return l

@task_group(group_id="group1")
def tg1(my_num):
    @task
    def print_num(num):
        return num

    @task
    def add_42(num):
        return num + 42

    print_num(my_num) >> add_42(my_num)

tg1_object = tg1.expand(my_num=random_length_list())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my requirements is number of group which you are taking from random_length_list() function will come from user input during execution